# Not able to use parts of a data.table

Tags: r, split, dataframe, data.table

I am having a really anoying problem in my code:

```
library(data.table)
a<-(letters=c(1:20))
b<-rnorm(1:20)
c<-rnorm(1:20)
d<-rnorm(1:20)
final<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)

e<-data.table(final)
g<-e[, lapply(.SD, sum), by =c("a"), .SDcols = 2:4] #calculates a summary of columns for every "by" statement in my large dataframe
h<-g[,2:4]
```

The vector h should include column 2-4 of g but it contains one value saying 2:4. However, some lines further up in my script the selection of certain columns with df[,columns] works.Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the data.table FAQ? Try `g[,2:4,with=FALSE]` instead.

Comment: `g[ , 2:4]` works "as expected" on recent versions of `data.table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit:

OP's question is moot in recent versions of `data.table`, since `g[ , 2:4]` works as expected (returns a `data.table` with all the rows and the 2nd-4th columns of `g`); `with=FALSE` is no longer necessary. Leaving the original answer since it still works.

---

The very first question in the [Data Table FAQ](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) describes this issue: (on why `DT[,5]` returns `5`)

```
Because, by default, unlike a data.frame, the 2nd argument is an 
expression which is evaluated within the scope of DT. 5 evaluates to 5.
```

And goes on to offer a workaround:

```
Having said this, there are some circumstances where referring to a column by
number is ok, such as a sequence of columns. In these situations just do:
DT[,5:10,with=FALSE]
```

or

```
DT[,c(1,4,10),with=FALSE]
```